# explicit POS tagged input provided and getting sentiment stanfordnlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying the code mentioned in question 11 from the [URL](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f).

I want to first give POS tagged input and second get sentiment analysis. First one I able to successfully get done. I able to print the tree and it looks fine. However second one returns me `-1` (it should return me `4=very positive`).

Please provide inputs/suggestions.

```
public static String test(){
    try{

        String grammer="/Users/lenin/jar/stanfordparser-master/stanford-parser/models/englishPCFG.ser.gz";

        // set up grammar and options as appropriate
        LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(grammer);
        String[] sent3 = { "movie", "was","very", "good","." };
        // Parser gets tag of second "can" wrong without help                    
        String[] tag3 = { "PRP", "VBD", "RB", "JJ","." };                             
        List sentence3 = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < sent3.length; i++) {
          sentence3.add(new TaggedWord(sent3[i], tag3[i]));
        }
        Tree parse = lp.parse(sentence3);
        parse.pennPrint();

        int sentiment_score = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(parse);
        System.out.println("score: "+sentiment_score);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a value of -1 because you haven't run any sentiment analysis. You've only parsed the sentence for grammatical structure.

You can, of course, run the sentiment analyzer via code, but, unfortunately, at the moment there isn't an easy lower-level interface to do so. That would be a good thing to add sometime! You essentially need to duplicate the processing that happens in the class `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator`:

1. Get a binarized tree from the parser (directly or by binarizing the tree returned)
2. Collapse unaries
3. Run the `SentimentCostAndGradient` class's `forwardPropagateTree`